# Observer not saving new price

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I created a custom observer to add some additional prices in product before placing order. 
I created an observer to **sales_order_place_before** and here's my code for observer:

```
<?php
class CustomPriceUpdate_Checkout_Model_Observer{
  public function update_price($observer){
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        $product_id = $product->getId();
        $price = $item->getPrice();
        $discountprice = 23;
        $newPrice = ($price)+($discountprice);
        $item->setCustomPrice($newPrice);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newPrice);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        $item->save();
        Mage::log($newPrice, null, "order.log", true);
    }
    $quote->save();    
  }
}
```

But its not saving the product price. I am getting the **new price** in the order.log file, that means by observer is triggering correctly.

It just need to save the new price.
Please someone suggest me any options.

Comment: Anyone with any suggestion ?

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. If you do not get an answer to your questions please do not create the same question again. Instead you can edit your original question to make it more clear or add more information. The question will re-appear on the homepage so it will be noticed again. If you have enough reputation, you can also offer a bounty to draw more attention

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of **change to order total** of the **magento checkout process**.

In a **typical order**, the **order totals** usually comprises of the following

- Sub Total
- Shipping Cost
- Taxes
- Discount
  based on these values the **total order grand total is calculated**.

Now if we want to add an additional **Credit Card Fee** or **Convince Fee** or Affiliate Discount or **any other order total** which will affect the order grand total we need to create a **magento module**. 
This extra fee which we are adding to the total would reflect in the

1. Checkout Page Order Total
2. Cart Page Order Total
3. My Account Order View Page
4. Print Order PDF
5. Order EMails
6. Admin Order View/Email/PDF
7. Admin Invoice View/Email/PDF
8. Admin Credit Memo View/Email/PDF

as you can see based on the above list this module is not be simple
So,**Let's begin** the **coding steps** to **perform above action**

---

**I will add a new order total called ‘Fee’ with a fixed cost of 10$.**

Here are few screenshots of the module after successful implementation
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Checkout Page Total Order Total Basics**
All the totals line items that show up the checkout page come from files located at folder `Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Address\Total`

In **magento before order is placed all order data is stored in a quote object and after order is placed it gets transferred to the order object**. 
The **quote totals** follow the **collector pattern** and we can add **collector as many collector classes.**To add collector to the quote object in our config.xml we add the lines

```
<global>
        <sales>
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <fee>
                        <class>fee/sales_quote_address_total_fee</class>
                    </fee>
                </totals>
            </quote>
       </sales>
</global>
```

This means whenever the totals are calculated for a quote, it will also call this class. **All collectors are called from the collectTotals() function in the Quote Model.**
In our **collector class we put in the code**

```
<?php
class Excellence_Fee_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Fee extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract{
    protected $_code = 'fee';

    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        parent::collect($address);

        $this->_setAmount(0);
        $this->_setBaseAmount(0);

        $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
        if (!count($items)) {
            return $this; //this makes only address type shipping to come through
        }


        $quote = $address->getQuote();

        if(Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::canApply($address)){ //your business logic
            $exist_amount = $quote->getFeeAmount();
            $fee = Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
            $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;
            $address->setFeeAmount($balance);
            $address->setBaseFeeAmount($balance);

            $quote->setFeeAmount($balance);

            $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() + $address->getFeeAmount());
            $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseFeeAmount());
        }
    }

    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $amt = $address->getFeeAmount();
        $address->addTotal(array(
                'code'=>$this->getCode(),
                'title'=>Mage::helper('fee')->__('Fee'),
                'value'=> $amt
        ));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

In above code,
The **two main functions** here are **collect() and fetch()**. 
In **collect function you add whatever amount you want to the order totals**, and **fetch() is used for display purposes. If this is done properly**, you should see your **order total line** in the **checkout and cart page**.

Here we are using **two fields fee_amount and base_fee_amount**, which contain our **fee amount**. We will have to see save these **two fields** to database, so in our **module installer file we add this code**

```
ALTER TABLE  `".$this->getTable('sales/quote_address')."` ADD  `fee_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
        ALTER TABLE  `".$this->getTable('sales/quote_address')."` ADD  `base_fee_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
```

**Order Page**
Till now, all code written has been done only for the **quote object**. But **after order is placed, we need to transfer all information to the order object**. 
As you would have seen above we are using two fields fee_amount and base_fee_amount, we now need to store these two fields in the order table as well. To do all the above we need to do two things. First in the config.xml file add this code inside the global tab,

```
<fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_address>
                <fee_amount><to_order>*</to_order></fee_amount>
                <base_fee_amount><to_order>*</to_order></base_fee_amount>
            </sales_convert_quote_address>
        </fieldsets>
```

and in our module install file

```
ALTER TABLE  `".$this->getTable('sales/order')."` ADD  `fee_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `".$this->getTable('sales/order')."` ADD  `base_fee_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
```

After doing this, these two fields should get saved to the order table from the quote table.